# Model seems overdone for single boolean value (switch on/off)

Tags: django

I would like admin to be able to switch a certain feature on/off on the website. It seems overdone to build an entire model for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What other ideas did you have apart from building a model?

Comment: you can put the value in `settings.py` and use the value in the desired part of the website

Comment: just add a boolian field for that feature. If it's True, feature will be visible.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a feature flag: https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html

Comment: https://github.com/cfpb/django-flags/tree/master/flags Feature flags is indeed an option. But since its only one flag I guess I'll just fire up a model.